# DateAdd /conversion

Tags: sql, sql-server

With this simple query working

```
SELECT dateadd(d,-13,Period_DateEnd) Period
FROM ReportingPeriod_tbl
```

once I add to a larger query I am getting a conversion error and I am clueless can anyone assist.

> 'Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.'

```
SELECT PeriodEnding FROM 
(
SELECT format(WeekEnd,'d-MMM-yy') PeriodEnding
FROM WeekEnd_tbl WHERE WeekEnd <= (SELECT TOP 1 WeekEnd FROM WeekEnd_tbl A WHERE A.IsCurrentWeek = 1)
UNION ALL
SELECT 
    format(Period_DateEnd,'MMM-yy') Period
FROM ReportingPeriod_tbl WHERE ReportingPeriod_ID <= (SELECT TOP 1 ReportingPeriod_ID FROM ReportingPeriod_tbl A 
WHERE Period_DateEnd >= (SELECT TOP 1 WeekEnd FROM WeekEnd_tbl A WHERE A.IsCurrentWeek = 1 ORDER BY WeekEnd))
UNION ALL
SELECT 
    dateadd(d,-13,Period_DateEnd) Period
FROM ReportingPeriod_tbl WHERE ReportingPeriod_ID <= (SELECT TOP 1 ReportingPeriod_ID FROM ReportingPeriod_tbl A 
WHERE Period_DateEnd >= (SELECT TOP 1 WeekEnd FROM WeekEnd_tbl A WHERE A.IsCurrentWeek = 1 ORDER BY WeekEnd))
) Period
```

Comment: The subquery does a UNION between two queries returning VARCHAR and the third is a DateTime. Try changing it to `format(dateadd(d,-13,Period_DateEnd),'MMM-yy')`, and make the aliases consistent.

Answer (score 0):

your string datetime format is worng

example:

```
select  dateadd(d,-13,'2018/04/28 12:00:00.000') --fine be ok
select  dateadd(d,-13,convert(datetime,'2018/04/28 12:00:00.000')) --fine be ok
select  dateadd(d,-13,'04/28')  --Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string
```

hope help you :)

---

new Qeustion:
[image]

change your query :

```
SELECT 
    dateadd(d,-13,Period_DateEnd) Period
FROM ReportingPeriod_tbl
```

to

```
SELECT 
    dateadd(d,-13,
        SUBSTRING(Period_DateEnd, 7, 4)  
        +'/'+SUBSTRING(Period_DateEnd, 4, 2) 
        +'/'+SUBSTRING(Period_DateEnd, 1, 2) 
        +SUBSTRING(Period_DateEnd, 11, 13)           
    ) Period
FROM ReportingPeriod_tbl
```

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/9b346/4/0)
and
Result:
[image]

Comment: Changing it to SELECT 
 dateadd(d,-13,convert(datetime,Period_dateend)) as suggested is still throwing the error ?

Comment: no, your Period_dateend string format is wrong like third example.

it's the point.

example your Period_dateend string is '20/04' or '2018/07'

Comment: I don't think I am following, I cannot adjust the format of the 'period_enddate in the other table so I need to adjust the query to deal with it ?

Comment: please query 'select period_enddate from  ReportingPeriod_tbl'
show your data for us.
different data format will get different answer

Comment: 21/07/2017 12:00:00 AM
23/06/2017 12:00:00 AM
26/05/2017 12:00:00 AM
21/04/2017 12:00:00 AM
24/03/2017 12:00:00 AM
17/02/2017 12:00:00 AM
20/01/2017 12:00:00 AM

Comment: Thanks for trying to help bit still getting error. Argument data type datetime is invalid for argument 1 of substring function. I'm using SQLServer2012 if that makes a difference

Comment: can you show your table (ReportingPeriod_tbl,WeekEnd_tbl) create sql script?
i need to know the type

Answer (score 0):

Please use this to avoid exceptions and figure out inproperly formatted strigs:

```
SELECT 
     [Period]       =   dateadd(d, -13, try_convert(datetime, [Period_DateEnd]))
    ,[Err_message]  =   iif(try_convert(datetime, [Period_DateEnd]) is null, 'Failed to convert string {' + [Period_DateEnd] + '} to datetime', null)
FROM
    [ReportingPeriod_tbl];
```

Full query: https://pastebin.com/3PPpkf2t

And one more thing:  you must have the same datetime format everywhere. Why? Its because 03/01/08. It is March 1 of 2008, or January 3 of 2008, or January 8 of 2003? :)